# Xcode: Unable to stop AVAudioPlayer music playing from sub class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

**STILL NO SOLUTION - REDUCED TEST CASE PROJECT HERE:**

http://www.friendlycode.co.uk/assets/Bugfix.zip

I'm new to Xcode/Objective C and have done a lot of research but cannot find an answer. There are loads of similar questions here but none of them have helped me solve this.

Files:

```
app.h
app.m
Settings.h
Settings.m
```

I have some background music playing which starts when the app is launched via ViewDidLoad in the ViewController.m file.

I am trying to stop this from the Settings.m file if the Music switch is touched and set to off.

Please see code below (have removed unnecessary outlets/methods etc)

The NSLog outputs 'attempting to stop audio' but audio is not stopped. I think I have referenced the ViewController class correctly so unsure why it won't stop?

app.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"

@interface ViewController : GAITrackedViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>
{
    // removed
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *BackgroundMusicPlayer;

@end
```

app.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Play Background music
    [self PlayBackgroundMusic];
}

-(void)PlayBackgroundMusic
{
    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                            pathForResource:@"music-file"
                            ofType:@"aiff"];

    NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError* err;

    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
    _BackgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err ){
        //bail!
        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //set our delegate and begin playback
        _BackgroundMusicPlayer.delegate = self;
        [_BackgroundMusicPlayer play];
        _BackgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
        _BackgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = 0;
        _BackgroundMusicPlayer.volume = 0.5;
    }
}
```

Settings.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "app.h"

@interface Settings : GAITrackedViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *BackButton;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *MusicSwitch;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *SoundFXSwitch;


    // Get instance of ViewController object
    ViewController *home;
}

-(IBAction)BackButton:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)ToggleMusic:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)ToggleSoundFX:(id)sender;


@end
```

Settings.m

```
#import "Settings.h"

@interface Settings ()

@end

@implementation Settings

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)ToggleMusic:(id)sender {

    // Get instance of ViewController object

    //home = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    if (MusicSwitch.on)
    {
        [home.BackgroundMusicPlayer play];
    }
    else {
       [home.BackgroundMusicPlayer stop];
        NSLog(@"Attempting to stop audio");

    }
}

-(IBAction)ToggleSoundFX:(id)sender {

    if (SoundFXSwitch.on)
    {
    }
    else{

    }
}

-(IBAction)BackButton:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I have created a reduced test case project if anyone would like to test their answers: http://www.friendlycode.co.uk/assets/Bugfix.zip

Comment: I have fixed it, by declaring the AVAudioPlayer in the AppDelegate.

Comment: I can't get your method working - please edit the reduced test case and upload somewhere. If it's working I'll award you the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Settings.h` , declare the `ViewController` property as `assign`

```
@interface Settings : GAITrackedViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
{
    @property (nonatomic, assign) ViewController *home;
}


-(IBAction)ToggleMusic:(id)sender {

    if (MusicSwitch.on)
    {
        [self.home.BackgroundMusicPlayer play];
    }
    else {

       [self.home.BackgroundMusicPlayer stop];
    }
}
```

From your `app.m` , assign the home property as self `_BackgroundMusicPlayer.home = self;`

```
-(void)PlayBackgroundMusic
{
    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                            pathForResource:@"music-file"
                            ofType:@"aiff"];

    NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError* err;

    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
    _BackgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err ){
        //bail!
        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //set our delegate and begin playback
        _BackgroundMusicPlayer.delegate = self;
        settingsViewObj.home = self; //recommended after the 'Settings' view allocation code.
        [_BackgroundMusicPlayer play];
        _BackgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
        _BackgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = 0;
        _BackgroundMusicPlayer.volume = 0.5;
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- Read more about object communication
- Read more about Objective C coding standards
- Read more about class hierarchy

Comment: Thanks for the answer and notes - I will be sure to read up more! I am receiving the error Property 'home' not found on object of type 'AVAudioPlayer *' when I add in the line *_BackgroundMusicPlayer.home = self;*. How do I add 'home' as an object of the AvAudioPlayer?

Comment: oh.really sorry. I have edited the answer. Write settingsViewObj.home = self; after the 'Settings' view allocation code.

Comment: Getting 'Use of undeclared identifier settingsViewObj'. Do I need to declare that? It isn't used anywhere else?

Comment: how are you accessing the 'Settings' class?

Comment: I didn't think I needed to. The app.h is imported in to the Settings.h file. Can't I access the app class this way? The code I have is all pasted above - there is no settingsViewObj variable declared. Forgive me I'm a little confused

Comment: how are you accessing the method 'ToggleMusic"?

Comment: By touching the 'Toggle music' switch in a modal window. It calls -(IBAction)ToggleMusic:(id)sender which is working as NSLog output's 'attempting to stop music'. This line is not working -> [self.home.BackgroundMusicPlayer play];

Comment: @FriendlyCode: did u resolve your issue? just send me the relevant class files to my email.email-id: shamsutk87@gmail.com

Comment: No still no solution - have just emailed you the latest reduced test case project. Thanks :-)

Comment: @FriendlyCode: I have replied back. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for sending over the working project and specifying exactly where the fixes were made.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the ViewController *home.

Your AvAudioPlayer object is in the app.h in the interface ViewController.

But in your code , you are not initialising the ViewController object "home" 
in settings.m. So effectively , you are trying to access and stop a player that
is not created.

To access the AVAudioPlayer object add the following code in your viewDidload of settings.h.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //initialise the audioPlayer object.
    home=[[ViewController alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hmm that hasn't worked either :(

Comment: Please can you have a look at the reduced test case?: http://www.friendlycode.co.uk/assets/Bugfix.zip

Comment: This is the problem. You can't access the backgroundMusicPlayer property of "home" without properly instantiating "home." Try: `self.home = [[ViewController alloc] init];` or perhaps `_home` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your code correctly, it seems you are creating a instance of your initial view controller and trying to stop the music player property of that instance. If that is the case, the music player you are trying to stop is already stopped, because it is a a separate instance of AVAudioPlayer that was created when you created an instance of your ViewController. In order to stop the music player from the first view controller, you could try this:

1. In the Settings.h file, add an AVAudioPlayer property just like in app.h

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic;
   ```
2. Then when segueing to the settings view controller, pass the audio player to the new controller using prepareForSegue:

   ```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
       if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueName"]) {
           if([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[YourSettingsClass class]]) {
               YourSettingsClass *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
               destination.backgroundMusic = self.BackgroundMusicPlayer;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. You should now be able to simply call `[self.backgroundMusic stop]` and stop your tunes.

Ensure that you `#import` your Settings controller class in your app class to access it in the prepareForSegue method.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I have tried this and I still cannot get this to work. I have given the Segue a name and linked it up with the code you supplied, and it all looks like it should work but just doesn't :-(

Comment: Please can you have a look at the reduced test case?: http://www.friendlycode.co.uk/assets/Bugfix.zip

Comment: I just got it working using the method I described above. Make sure you give your segue an identifier in the storyboard and that your switch is correctly hooked up to your settings class as an IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the instance of an object of another class created by it, by importing
 it.Here You have to access the same object instance , in order to stop the AVAudioPlayer.

So you have to place the object somewhere unique, like AppDelegate.

Try declaring the AVAudioPlayer in the appdelegate.h.

In Appdeleagte.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *BackgroundMusicPlayer;
```

and in your app.h you can access the player as follows.

AppDelegate *appDelegate;

```
//in your viewDidLoad
    appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 

//in your PlayBackGroundMusic
       appdelegate.avAudioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];
       [appDelegate.avAudioplayer play];
```

in your settings.h

AppDeleagte *appDelegate;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //initialise the audioPlayer object.
    appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 


}
```

you can stop the player by

```
[appDelegate.avAudioPlayer stop];
```

You can download the fixed project  [here](http://mydeveloperzone.in/wp-content/uploads/Bugfix%202.zip)

Comment: hi, you can download the fixed files here http://mydeveloperzone.in/wp-content/uploads/Bugfix%202.zip